# Nivo slider different transition effect for each image

Tags: nivo-slider

I am working on a script that uses Nivo Slider. I have this working but I would like to make each image have a different transition effect.

The images are loaded using a MySQL call which returns the ImageName and Effect as PHP variables.

```
$row_Signage['PromotionImage'] = ImageName: image_1.png
$row_Signage['Effect'] = Effect: slideInRight
```

The config code for the Nivo Slider is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var TimeLapse = '<?php echo $row_Setting['TimeLapse'];?>';    
  var Effect = '<?php echo $row_Setting['Effect'];?>';  
  console.log("EFFECT", Effect);
  var AnimSpeed = '<?php echo $row_Setting['AnimSpeed'];?>';    
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: Effect,
    slices: 30,
    boxCols: 16,
    boxRows: 8,
    animSpeed: AnimSpeed,
    pauseTime: TimeLapse, 
    startSlide: 0,
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: false,
    controlNavThumbs: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    manualAdvance: false,
    //prevText: 'Prev',
    //nextText: 'Next',
    randomStart: false,
    beforeChange: function(){},
    afterChange: function(){},
    slideshowEnd: function(){},
    lastSlide: function(){},
    afterLoad: function(){}
});
});
```

I then have a PHP While loop to display the images:

```
if($totalRows_Signage > 0){
    while($row_Signage = mysql_fetch_array($Signage)){
          echo '<img src="/'.$ImagePath .''.$row_Signage['PromotionImage'].'" data-transition="'.$row_Signage['Effect'].'"/> ';
      $i++;
    }
} else {
    echo '<img src="/'.$DefaultImagePath .'"/>';
}
```

The issue I have is the echo statement in the while loop is not picking up the data-transition variable, I have tried a number of ways at writing the line that echo's out the images. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This question can be closed under the official reason of "typo / unrepro" - DCJones, you may be able to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

On returning to this issue it was actually working with the code I posted. Odd but it works.